# Keep Bat file ontop while it runs

Tags: batch-file

How do I make my bat file stay on top while it opens other programs and files?

Comment: http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use 3rd Party software like [Desk Pins](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/deskpins.html) to force any window to stick on top